# how to remove Loading time focus in etherpad?

Tags: etherpad

My issue is posted on below link

https://github.com/ether/etherpad-lite/issues/2231

if anyone have solution then plz give ans.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

click on below link to get answer.
I made one plugin which disable the init time focus.

https://github.com/odoo/odoo/tree/master/addons/pad/static/plugin/ep_disable_init_focus